# B&W horror sci-fi movie where a mad scientist sends a monster to kidnap the female lead, ends with a hairy shoulder

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I don't know the name of the movie and I haven't seen it completely. I just watched it for the last 15-20 minutes and so, I can't tell all the details.

The movie was in black and white. I saw the movie from the scene where the mad scientist sent a humanoid, gorilla like bipedal monster (its hide was hairy or grassy) to capture the female lead. The lady just had a shower and was wrapped in a towel when the monster captured her.

The protagonist went to the scientist's hideout and after a long fight (he destroyed the lab and killed or defeated the monster) he rescued the heroine still lying on the OT, unconscious and wrapped in the same towel.

The hero took the girl to his car where she gained her senses and kissed and embraced her rescuer. The closing scene shows the hero is still in her embrace, unbeknown to the fact that the girl's shoulder is turning hairy, suggesting that the scientist was indeed successful in his vile plan.

I saw the movie some 6-9 years ago on the Zee MGM channel. The time was probably 10-11 AM IST (Indian Standard Time). It was in English and had subtitles. It  was an older movie probably during the 1950-1960s.

The movie didn't have any "alien" element (extra terrestrial) entity in it. The female lead was a blonde and the protagonist was wearing a suit.

Comment: Do yo remember when you may have seen it, the language it was in? Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details.

Comment: None of these seem to exactly fit, but there are elements similar to what you;re describing, so give them a go...possibly, 'Not of This Earth' (1957), 'The Brain Eaters' (1958), 'The Creeping Terror' (1963), 'The Human Duplicators' (1965)....best I can do for now :-)

Comment: @wcullen The movie didn't have any "alien" element (extra terrestrial) entity in it.

Comment: One last try :-)  Joseph green's 1962 'The Brain That Wouldn't Die'..? It seems to fit right up until your description of the ending...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVXzYmixGDE

Comment: I'm going to ask was it "Bride Of The Monster" by Ed Wood? Can't imagine anyone showing that on TV, due to humanitarian reasons though.Key question: What color where the monster's eyes?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds very much like [*The Brain That Wouldn't Die*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brain_That_Wouldn%27t_Die) (alternate title, *The Head That Wouldn't Die*).  A transplant scientist "saves" his girlfriend after she's decapitated in a car accident, then looks for a new body for her.  He keeps a "monster" locked up in his lab, assembled during his experiments, and in the end uses the monster to kidnap a woman to "donate" a body -- only to be thwarted by the "donor's" boyfriend, who in the process burns down the lab with the still-living head, monster, and mad doctor still inside.

Comment: @saswat The Mystery Science Theater version is here: http://www.club-mst3k.com/episodes/513-the-brain-that-wouldn-t-die (even if the full movie isn't available, you might recognize imagery from the 'Favorite Moments' video).

Comment: Sadly, no hairy shoulder, though...

Comment: Jan in a pan.  Someone even made a model kit.  https://www.monstersinmotion.com/cart/item-list-iz-c-19_91/brain-that-wouldnt-die-jan-in-the-pan-16-scale-resin-model-kit-p-3612.html

Comment: The monster (who communed with Jan in the Pan) was in no way apelike and in fact was not a mutated human but rather sort of an agglomeration of parts as a side-effect of the scientist's research--an entirely artificial organism played by Eddie Carmel, The Jewish Giant who was famous for being a very tall guy who was Jewish and photographed IIRC by his cousin who was IIRC Arbus (married to the actor Alan Arbus).